# Расшифровуется ли как-то айпи, по городу, стране и т.д?

Tags: ip

Есть ип
111.222.333.444

Соответствует ли каждая группа, например стране, городу конкретному, адресу?..

Например

первая группа: 111 - страна определяется ( Украина 100-150, США 1-100 ...)

Группа: 222 - определяет город в стране

Группа: 333 - определяет адрес

Comment: Откройте любой интернет магазин и вы удивитесь тому, как сайт ошибается в вашем местоположении. Сколько изучал этот вопрос, в своё время, определить можно местонахождение владельца IP адреса (имеется ввиду адрес юридического лица), а не пользователя. И информация берётся у регистратора. IP - это, увы, не GPS маячок. Самый лучший вариант - определять до страны. И то, если пользователь не пользуется анонимайзерами или VPN сетями.

Comment: По ипу не узнать, ложные данные будут, а вот `bssId` - вот это уже да.

Comment: IANA выделяет группы адресов, по первым цифрам одному из 5 глобальным LIR, по континентам. https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml  Причем часть адресов роздана некоторым отдельным организациям без привязки к местоположению. Если ip у LIR, дальше смотрим его таблицы. Но никто не мешает мне, имея автономную систему, получив группу адресов, переехать с ней в другую страну или давать их клиентам во всех странах

Answer (score 3):

Так вот что прямо группы по циферкам - нет. Тем более с точностью до адреса.

Но есть куча обновляемых сервисов, которыми можно воспользоваться с каким-то приближением. Начиная с [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/ru/geoip2-databases), и заканчивая более актуальным для России [Sypex](http://sypexgeo.net/).

В любом случае вы можете получить результат плюс-минус континент (например, я сейчас, находясь в пригороде Питера, разными сервисами определяюсь и как Калуга, и как Оклэнд).

P.S. проверил - по мнению 2ip я вообще в Москве где-то :)